# Javascript passing an encoded url to window.location.href

Tags: javascript

I'd like to redirect a page with javascript using the following code:

```
    var s = 'http://blahblah/' + encodeURIComponent(something);
    alert(s);
    window.location.href = s;
```

The alert shows the correct encoded url but when I pass it to window.locaion.href, it redirects the page to the unencoded url which is wrong.
How could I do it properly?
Thanks

Comment: it's working fine at my side.

Comment: For me it's fine with chrome but not with firefox.

Comment: For me its working in both browsers.

Comment: Actually it's working on both. But firefox shows the unencoded url in  the url bar.

Comment: Sounds like a versions issue! For interest's sake could you tell us what versions of what browser did **not** work for you?

Answer (score 6):

This could be related to (a) using firefox or (b) specific APIs that you're feeding `encodedComponent` into, like Google search.

Here's one tested solution on Firefox-stable:

```
var clearComponent = 'flowers for my boyfriend & husband on valentines';
var encodedComponent = encodeURIComponent(clearComponent);
var googleSafeComponent = encodedComponent.replace(/%20/g,'+');  // replaces spaces with plus signs for Google and similar APIs
var completeURI = 'http://google.com/?q=' + googleSafeComponent;
window.location = completeURI;
```

Or all in one line:

```
window.location = 'http://google.com/?q=' + encodeURIComponent('flowers for my boyfriend & husband on valentines').replace(/%20/g,'+');
```

`window.location` implies `window.location.href` so you can save some letters. ;)